# Gcc-4.8 in Ubuntu-20.04-lts docker container

Tags: docker, gcc, dockerfile, ubuntu-20.04, gcc4.8

I'm trying to install *gcc-4.8* in ubuntu-20.04 docker image using below dockerfile.

```yaml
# Pull base image.
FROM ubuntu:20.04
..............
...................
........................
## Get gcc 4.8.5 and build it
RUN wget http://mirror.keystealth.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz \
&& tar xzf gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz && \
cd gcc-4.8.5 && \
./contrib/download_prerequisites && \
cd .. && mkdir gccbuild && cd gccbuild && \
../gcc-4.8.5/configure \
--prefix="/opt/gcc" \
--enable-shared --with-system-zlib --enable-threads=posix \
--enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-checking --enable-gnu-indirect-function \
--enable-languages="c,c++" --disable-bootstrap \
&& make all && make install
```

When i build the image, it shows below error message.

```
--2022-03-03 10:52:56--  ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/mpfr-2.4.2.tar.bz2
           => 'mpfr-2.4.2.tar.bz2'
Resolving gcc.gnu.org (gcc.gnu.org)... 8.43.85.97, 2620:52:3:1:0:246e:9693:128c
Connecting to gcc.gnu.org (gcc.gnu.org)|8.43.85.97|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /pub/gcc/infrastructure ... done.
==> SIZE mpfr-2.4.2.tar.bz2 ... 1077886
==> PASV ... couldn't connect to 10.88.55.69  port 53847: Connection timed out
Retrying.
```

Since *ftp* access is blocked at firewall in our organization. Hence i do not have *ftp* site in `dockerfile` to download gcc-4.8.5, I'm not sure from where it is trying to connect via *ftp*.

Can someone help me to install gcc-4.8 using dockerfile?

Comment: Are you sure you correctly modified your dockerfile and are using the new one? Because I can't reproduce the issue that downloading from the mirror URL attempts to download via FTP (that would imply a redirect, which I don't see if I run `curl -v http://mirror.keystealth.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz -o /dev/null`, it just directly downloads from there). Can you post the output of running the new Dockerfile? specifically the part where it downloads gcc?

Comment: @Generous Badger, I have updated the question with new Dockerfile problem.

Comment: It seems likely that's something the `download_prerequisites` script is doing.  Do you need this specific version of gcc built from source, or can you `apt-get install` a prebuilt toolchain?

Comment: Yes i need `gcc-4.8` specific version to build our old code. it would be good, if i get some ways to install the same.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that the file it's trying to download over ftp is not gcc itself. @DavidMaze seems correct: the script itself seems to have hardcoded URLs. Good news is that all of those URLs also have corresponding http urls (i.e. ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/ is also accessible via https://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/), so something as simple as running `sed` to replace `ftp://` with `https://` before executing the script should be sufficient.